# on a server does master boot record formating of the disk support the dynamic disk type?

Tags: partitioning, mbr, gpt, dynamic-disk, basic-disk

If I convert a disk from basic to dynamic is it possible to format it to master boot record (MBR) or is it just possible to format with GPT?

Answer (score 0):

There are two entirely orthogonal dimensions here:

- **Partition table type** -- This is MBR vs. GPT. The disk may be one or the other, but not both. ([Hybrid MBRs](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) are, in a sense, both, but they're illegal by the GPT spec.)
- **Basic vs. dynamic disks** -- In Microsoft terminology, a "basic disk" is an MBR or GPT disk on which filesystems reside directly in partitions. A  "dynamic disk," OTOH, uses Microsoft's [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) to enable creating filesystems that consume part of a partition or that span multiple partitions. This is Microsoft's version of a [logical volume management (LVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) configuration. By whatever name, dynamic/LDM/LVM configurations are much more flexible -- but also more complex -- than "basic" disk setups.

Thus, the MBR or GPT configuration of a disk exists "underneath" its configuration as "basic" vs. "dynamic." In setting up a disk, you normally select MBR vs. GPT and then select "basic" vs. "dynamic" -- although in practice, an OS installer may make both these decisions for you, and may not even tell you what decisions it's making.

Unfortunately, the Windows partitioning software has a tendency to convert "basic" disks to an LDM/dynamic configuration without warning. This can wreak havoc if you're multi-booting or sharing a removable disk with another OS. If you run into this problem, you can use tools like [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) to convert back to a "basic" (plain MBR or GPT) setup.

Most tools can convert MBR to GPT or vice-versa only by completely deleting all the partitions on the disk. IIRC, EaseUS can do so losslessly. So can my [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) software, albeit with some caveats concerning partition size and layout.